# Do most apartment HVACs take in outdoor air or do they usually only recirculate indoor air?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

The apartment is a new construction, where each unit has its own HVAC (air handler?), and it looks like something like this:
[image: in the closet]

When we turn on the heat or AC, conditioned air comes out of the vents. We all know that. The thing I'm not sure of is, where do the air come from? Is it recirculated indoor air? Or drawn from the outdoors? Or a mixture of both? I know some commercial HVAC systems have the ability to mix indoor and outdoor air using dampers.

Comment: you can see your HVAC's intake on the right side of the picture, behind that giant grate. AFAIK, most residential systems don't exchange outside air, save some of the newest heat-exchanging models.

Comment: Does _your_ unit look "something" like this or "exactly" like this? i.e., is this your unit or a pic you found at random on the internet? Provide some closer shots of your actual unit, people may be able to determine if/where there's some outside air coming into the unit.

Answer (score 3):

The Building Code requires all “Buildings shall be provided with natural ventilation”. (See ICC Section 1203.1)

I suppose it depends on where you live if the outside air is brought in and mixed with the existing air or if a window can be opened.

If you live in a high rise residential building the windows are sealed and it’s more likely to have outside air brought in through the mechanical system.

The code says “Natural ventilation shall be through windows, doors, louvres, or other openings to the outdoors “.  (See 1203.4)

The “minimum amount is 4% of the floor area” (See 1203.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Lee Sam 's answer, the majority of your air will be recirculated by being sucked into the return vent located near the floor on the outside of that closet. From thee, it will be forced through heating or cooling coils by the blower motor and then get routed out the supply ducts. There should be an air filter by that vent so make sure you change it often.

Comment: The reason for this is that reheating or recooling already conditioned air is much more efficient that heating/cooling outside air.  This makes your HVAC bill lower each month.